# Rbind Difference of rows

Tags: r, diff, rbind

I want to determine the difference of each row and have that total difference rbinded at the end. Below is a sample dataset:

```
DATE <- as.Date(c('2016-11-28','2016-11-29'))
TYPE <- c('A', 'B')
Revenue <- c(2000, 1000)
Sales <- c(1000, 4000)
Price <- c(5.123, 10.234)
Material <- c(10000, 7342)
df<-data.frame(DATE, TYPE, Revenue, Sales, Price, Material)

df

        DATE TYPE Revenue Sales  Price Material
1 2016-11-28    A    2000  1000  5.123    10000
2 2016-11-29    B    1000  4000 10.234     7342
```

How Do I calculate the Difference of Each of the Columns to produce this total:

```
        DATE TYPE Revenue Sales  Price Material
1 2016-11-28    A    2000  1000  5.123    10000
2 2016-11-29    B    1000  4000 10.234     7342
3 DIFFERENCE        -1000  3000  5.111    -2658
```

I can easily do it by columns but having trouble doing it by row.

Any help would be great thanks!

Comment: What do you expect in output in case when there are more than two rows?

Comment: Do you have only 2 rows in your data set for which you want to calculate the difference? Or there are more rows?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As 'DATE' is `Date` class, we may need to change it to `character` before proceeding with `rbind`ing with string "DIFFERENCE".  Other than that, subset the numeric columns of 'df', loop it with `lapply`, get the difference, concatenate with the 'DATE' and 'TYPE', and `rbind` with original dataset.

```
df$DATE <- as.character(df$DATE)
rbind(df, c(DATE = "DIFFERENCE", TYPE= NA, lapply(df[-(1:2)], diff)))
#        DATE TYPE Revenue Sales  Price Material
#1 2016-11-28    A    2000  1000  5.123    10000
#2 2016-11-29    B    1000  4000 10.234     7342
#3 DIFFERENCE <NA>   -1000  3000  5.111    -2658
```